# How to determine the time lag at different time intervals between two correlated variables

Tags: r, statistics

I have two variables, x and y, measured at one minute intervals for over two years. The average **daily** values of x and y are almost 90% correlated. However, when I analyze x and y in one minute intervals they are only 50% correlated. How can I detect the time interval at which this correlation becomes 90%? Ideally I'd like to do this in R.

I'm new to statistics/econometrics, so my apologies if this question is very basic!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking here. What do you mean by x and y being 90 "percent" correlated? Do you mean you get a correlation coefficient of .9?

Beyond this clarification you can absolutely have a situation where the average of 2 variables is more correlated than any individual subset of the data. In other words order matters, so the correlation of the average is not the average of the correlation. For example, this R code shows if we took 3 measurements each hour for 2 hours (6 measurements total), the overall correlation is .5, while the correlation of the average hourly measure is a perfect 1. Essentially when you take the correlation of averages you are effectively removing the impact of the order your measurement values are distributed within the interval you are averaging over, which ends up actually being very important when taking the correlations. Let me know if I missed something about your question though.

```
X=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Y=c(3,2,1,6,5,4)


cor(X,Y)

HourAvgX=c(mean(X[1:3]),mean(X[4:6]))
HourAvgY=c(mean(Y[1:3]),mean(Y[4:6]))


cor(HourAvgX,HourAvgY)
```